# Gmail API return chats with "SENT" label

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

Using the Gmail API call

> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id

return **chats** with label **SENT**

I have used the following code for getting the message content

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/$useremail/messages/$messageid?format=full";
$response = $gmailInstance->performHttpRequest($gmailAuthObj, $useremail, $url);
$responseBody = json_decode($response->getResponseBody(), TRUE);
```

I got the following response for the above API call

```
{
 "id": msgid,
 "threadId": threadid,
 "labelIds": [
     "CHAT",
     "SENT"
 ],
 "snippet": "sometext",
 "historyId": 7 digit numeric,
 "internalDate": "1371160444361",
 "payload": {
     "partId": "",
     "mimeType": "text/html",
     "filename": "",
     "headers": [{
         "name": "From",
         "value": "Test User \u003ctuser@tdom.com\u003e"
      }],
      "body": {
          "size": 20,
          "data": somerandomstring
      }
 },
 "sizeEstimate": 100
 }
```

Does anybody know why the API response return chat message with SENT label in it? Is there a way to avoid this (SENT label from chat response)?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking about :) That is the correct response data. Do you want the `text/plain` or the `text/html` part of the response or something along those lines?

Comment: @Tholle I want to know why the API response return SENT label for a chat message. Is there a way to avoid this (SENT label from chat response)?